# Any particular reason why this switch-case statement in js is returning undefined?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, case

Here is my code. I have cross checked with online docs and couldn't find any reason for this to not work.

```js
let marks = 90;
switch (marks) {
  case 1:
    if (marks <= 100 && marks >= 80) {
      console.log("Very Good");
    }
    break;
  case 2:
    if (marks >= 60 && marks <= 79) {
      console.log("Good");
    }
    break;
  case 3:
    if (marks >= 30 && marks <= 59) {
      console.log("Can do better");
    }
    break;
  case 4:
    if (marks < 30) {
      console.log("Fail");
    }
    break;
}
```

Comment: `case value` works like `if (toCheck == value)`, `toCheck` being the variable you pass through the `switch` statement, so in your example, it would do the following: 1. Check if `marks == 1`  2. Check if `marks == 2`  and so on

Comment: You should just use `if` and `else if` statements, you don't need `switch/case`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let marks = 90;
switch (marks<=100) {
 case marks <= 100 && marks>=80:
    console.log("Very Good");
    break
 case ( marks >=60 && marks <= 79) :
    console.log("Good")
    break;
 case (marks >= 30 && marks <=59):
    console.log("Can do better");  
    break;
  case (marks < 30) :   
    console.log("Fail");  
    break;
  }
```

This should work your switch cases don't make sense

Comment: This is a very strange way to write it.

Comment: Actually no, `switch` isn‘t passed boolean, see *[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch)*

Comment: @natre214 In this case it is, since the value of `marks <= 100` is a boolean.

Comment: Really? Ok but I think that‘s not really Clean Code :)